# Use first letter of file to highlight it in the directory tree in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

When I want to quickly navigate to a file in a normal operating systems file tree I click into the tree then I press a letter and it will move to the files starting with this letter. Continuous pressing of that letter will move through all files starting with this letter. I'm used to that behavior and find it very intuitive.

But in PhpStorm they changed that, when I click in the tree and type the letter this "Search for:" window appears and I need to enter a lot of the file name in order to reliable highlight the file. In some cases it will even move to files in a completely other place in the tree as it doesn't start its search from the first letters of the files but those that match most.

How can i deactivate this "feature" of PhpStorm and is it even possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't deactivate this & you can't switch to Windows Explorer type of search-as-you-type file searching.

Comment: Very bad thing no workaround for this? How do they come to invent back the wheel in this crazy way. In every system everyware it works like that people is used to that, only in this phpstorm and we cant change it back. I will switch IDE asap.

Comment: Is this feature what really makes IDE for you? Well.... Jokes aside, you can submit this as a new feature request to JetBrains tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue